# Why is Spark corrupting part 2 of multipart upload

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, amazon-emr

I have a spark job that, once done, uploads output to S3 in json format.

```
dataframe.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).json(file_path)
```

Yesterday though, one json it uploaded was incomplete, rest jsons looked fine as usual. Below is the snippet of logs about that one file. I have extracted these from 2 log files out of the many that were generated for that job run.

log file 1

```
20/04/07 13:12:41 INFO MultipartUploadOutputStream: uploadPart: partNum 1 of 's3://bucket/part-00072-50d3246e-e18c-4058-9e1c-ad714305c92f-c000.json' from local file '/mnt/s3/emrfs-5360609960688228490/0000000000', 134217728 bytes in 5577 ms, md5: qg7f22UwVchHRejYe+41GQ== md5hex: aa0edfdb653055c84745e8d87bee3519
20/04/07 13:12:43 INFO MultipartUploadOutputStream: uploadPart: partNum 2 of 's3://bucket/part-00072-50d3246e-e18c-4058-9e1c-ad714305c92f-c000.json' from local file '/mnt/s3/emrfs-5360609960688228490/0000000001', 69266128 bytes in 1322 ms, md5: hOJmAWIoAMs2EtyBCuUw2g== md5hex: 84e26601622800cb3612dc810ae530da
20/04/07 13:12:44 INFO Executor: Finished task 72.0 in stage 549.0 (TID 413542). 212642 bytes result sent to driver
20/04/07 13:12:44 INFO DefaultMultipartUploadDispatcher: Completed multipart upload of 2 parts 203483856 bytes
20/04/07 13:12:44 INFO SparkHadoopMapRedUtil: No need to commit output of task because needsTaskCommit=false: attempt_20200407131212_0549_m_000072_0
```

log file 2

```
20/04/07 13:12:37 INFO Executor: Running task 72.1 in stage 549.0 (TID 413637)
20/04/07 13:12:44 INFO Executor: Executor is trying to kill task 72.1 in stage 549.0 (TID 413637), reason: another attempt succeeded
20/04/07 13:12:44 INFO MultipartUploadOutputStream: uploadPart: partNum 2 of 's3://bucket/part-00072-50d3246e-e18c-4058-9e1c-ad714305c92f-c000.json' from local file '/mnt/s3/emrfs-3565489585808272492/0000000001', 1 bytes in 43 ms, md5: y7GE3Y4FyXCeXcrtqgSVzw== md5hex: cbb184dd8e05c9709e5dcaedaa0495cf
20/04/07 13:12:45 INFO MultipartUploadOutputStream: uploadPart: partNum 1 of 's3://bucket/part-00072-50d3246e-e18c-4058-9e1c-ad714305c92f-c000.json' from local file '/mnt/s3/emrfs-3565489585808272492/0000000000', 134217728 bytes in 1395 ms, md5: qg7f22UwVchHRejYe+41GQ== md5hex: aa0edfdb653055c84745e8d87bee3519
20/04/07 13:12:46 INFO DefaultMultipartUploadDispatcher: Completed multipart upload of 2 parts 134217729 bytes
20/04/07 13:12:46 INFO Executor: Executor interrupted and killed task 72.1 in stage 549.0 (TID 413637), reason: another attempt succeeded
```

As can be seen from the logs, the second task wanted to stop itself once it came to know that first one has uploaded the file. But it wasn't able to rollback entirely and in turn ended up overwriting with partial data(1 byte). That json now looks like this

```
{"key": "v}
```

instead of

```
{"key": "value"}
```

and this causes the reader of json to throw exception. I have tried to search this issue but can not see anyone ever posting about it. Has anyone faced this issue here? Is this a bug in spark? How can I overcome this?

Comment: looks more like a bug in the AWS S3 connector. Tasks should not manifest any output until job commit, but their code is doing that

Comment: thanks for your input @steve-loughran, do you know if this is a known issue to aws? Any ticket that I can track to find out if they resolved it in any version?

Comment: not my codebase; no idea where to begin. FWIW I do think having a task manifest data at the destination is wrong as spark doesn't expect it. the EMR spark committer *and* the hadoop one with the v2 algorithm both do this -and its dangerous